# Need to change this object into this array of objects in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, object

I've been given with this data in an endpoint and I need to change it so it can work in a menu that I'm currently working on but it's all messed up. I could really use some help here, fellas

This is the original one

```
{
  SubMenu: {
    Main: [
      {
        Main: "Database",
        SubMenu: {
          Name: "Manage",
          Path: "databaseManage",
          icon: "mdi-database",
          innerMenu: "false",
        },
      },
      {
        Main: "Database",
        SubMenu: {
          Name: "Request to Remove",
          Path: "requestToRemove",
          icon: "mdi-database",
          innerMenu: "false",
        },
      },
      {
        Main: "Account",
        SubMenu: {
          Name: "Audit",
          Path: "audit",
          icon: "mdi-account",
          innerMenu: "false",
        },
      },
      {
        Main: "Account",
        SubMenu: {
          Name: "Manage",
          Path: "accountManage",
          icon: "mdi-account",
          innerMenu: "false",
        },
      },
      {
        Main: "Assistance",
        SubMenu: {
          Name: "Requests",
          Path: "requests",
          icon: "mdi-account-question",
          innerMenu: "false",
        },
      },
      {
        Main: "Admin",
        SubMenu: {
          Name: "Delegates",
          Path: "delegates",
          icon: "mdi-clipboard-list",
          innerMenu: "false",
        },
      },
      {
        Main: "Insights",
        SubMenu: {
          Name: "Charts",
          Path: "charts",
          icon: "mdi-lightbulb-on",
          innerMenu: "false",
        },
      },
      {
        Main: "Insights",
        SubMenu: {
          Name: "Reports",
          Path: "reports",
          icon: "mdi-lightbulb-on",
          innerMenu: "false",
        },
      },
      {
        Main: "DBA Admin",
        SubMenu: {
          Name: "Assignemets",
          Path: "dbaAdmin",
          icon: "mdi-face-recognition",
          innerMenu: "false",
        },
      },
      {
        Main: "DBA Admin",
        SubMenu: {
          Name: "DBA Management",
          Path: "dbaManagement",
          icon: "mdi-face-recognition",
          innerMenu: "false",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
},
```

and this is how it should be:

```
[
  {
    main: "Databases",
    submenu: [
      {
        name: "Manage",
        path: "databaseManage",
        icon: "mdi-database",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
      {
        name: "Request to remove",
        path: "requestToRemove",
        icon: "mdi-database",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
      {
        name: "Advisor",
        path: "advisorView",
        icon: "mdi-database",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    main: "Accounts",
    submenu: [
      {
        name: "Manage",
        path: "accountManage",
        icon: "mdi-account",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
      {
        name: "Audit",
        path: "audit",
        icon: "mdi-account",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    main: "Assistance",
    submenu: [
      {
        name: "Requests",
        path: "requests",
        icon: "mdi-account-question",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    main: "Admin",
    submenu: [
      {
        name: "Delegates",
        path: "delegates",
        icon: "mdi-clipboard-list",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    main: "Insights",
    submenu: [
      {
        name: "Charts",
        path: "charts",
        icon: "mdi-lightbulb-on",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
      {
        name: "Reports",
        path: "reports",
        icon: "mdi-lightbulb-on",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
      {
        name: "Volume Reduction Tracker",
        path: "volumeReductionTracker",
        icon: "mdi-lightbulb-on",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    main: "DBA Admin",
    submenu: [
      {
        name: "Assignments",
        path: "dbaAdmin",
        icon: "mdi-face-recognition",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
      {
        name: "DBA Management",
        path: "dbaManagement",
        icon: "mdi-face-recognition",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
      {
        name: "Reporting Tool",
        path: "reportingTool",
        icon: "mdi-face-recognition",
        innerMenu: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    main: "Honk admin",
    submenu: [
      { name: "Roles", path: "roles", icon: "mdi-duck", innerMenu: false },
      { name: "Users", path: "users", icon: "mdi-duck", innerMenu: false },
      {
        name: "Logs",
        icon: "mdi-duck",
        innerMenu: [
          { name: "Honk Administrative", path: "logAdministrative" },
          { name: "SNow to Athena - Dev", path: "serviceNowDev" },
          { name: "SNow to Athena - Prod", path: "serviceNowProd" },
        ],
      },
    ],
```

any help? I tried using computed properties, also tried doing Object.keys, values, etc and I don't get any close to the solution

Comment: You could use lodash.camelCase library to convert the keys to camelCase https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#camelCase

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that gets there.

```
function shuffle(arr) {
var a = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (a.some(o => o["main"] === arr[i]["Main"])) {
        let idx = a.findIndex(x => {
            return x['main'] == arr[i].Main;
        });
        let copy = arr[i].SubMenu;
        a[idx].submenu.push(copy)
    } else {
        let copy = arr[i]["SubMenu"]
        let obj = {
            main: arr[i]["Main"],
            submenu: [copy]
        }
        a.push(obj);
    }
}
return a;
}
```

This will work if you pass in the Main array